# No thread-bound request found when setting attribute to HttpSession

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-security, oauth-2.0, httpsession

I'm going to use oauth2 login. I am using Spring Boot 3.0 with Spring Security 6. Logging in and saving user information to the database was successful, but then an error occurs when saving user information to HttpSession. I wonder why this error occurs and I am looking for a way to fix it.

Below is my code.

SecurityConfig

```kotlin
package app.myoun.zzalhub.application.config

import app.myoun.zzalhub.application.auth.Role
import app.myoun.zzalhub.application.service.OAuth2UserService
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.invoke
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfig(
    protected val oAuth2UserService: OAuth2UserService
) {

    @Bean
    protected fun httpSecurityConfigure(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
        http {
            csrf { disable() }

            headers { frameOptions { disable() } }

            authorizeHttpRequests {
                authorize("/", permitAll)

                authorize("/api/**", hasRole(Role.USER.name))

                authorize(anyRequest, permitAll)
            }

            oauth2Login {
                userInfoEndpoint { userService = oAuth2UserService }
                defaultSuccessUrl("/", false)
            }

            logout {
                logoutSuccessUrl = "/"
            }
        }
        return http.build()
    }
}
```

OAuth2UserService

```kotlin
package app.myoun.zzalhub.application.service

import app.myoun.zzalhub.application.auth.OAuthAttributes
import app.myoun.zzalhub.application.auth.SessionUser.Companion.toSessionUser
import app.myoun.zzalhub.application.entity.UserEntity
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpSession
import jakarta.transaction.Transactional
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.userinfo.DefaultOAuth2UserService
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.userinfo.OAuth2UserRequest
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.userinfo.OAuth2UserService
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AuthenticationException
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.user.DefaultOAuth2User
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.user.OAuth2User
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service

@Service
class OAuth2UserService(protected val userService: UserService, protected val httpSession: HttpSession): OAuth2UserService<OAuth2UserRequest, OAuth2User> {

    private val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(javaClass)
    private val objectMapper: ObjectMapper = ObjectMapper()

    @Throws(OAuth2AuthenticationException::class)
    override fun loadUser(userRequest: OAuth2UserRequest): OAuth2User {
        val delegate = DefaultOAuth2UserService()
        val oauth2User = delegate.loadUser(userRequest)

        val registrationId = userRequest.clientRegistration.registrationId
        val userNameAttributeName = userRequest.clientRegistration.providerDetails.userInfoEndpoint.userNameAttributeName

        val attributes = OAuthAttributes.of(registrationId, userNameAttributeName, oauth2User.attributes)

        val user = saveOrUpdate(attributes)
        httpSession.setAttribute("user", user.toSessionUser())

        return DefaultOAuth2User(mutableSetOf(SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.role.key)), attributes.attributes, attributes.nameAttributeKey)
    }

    @Transactional
    private fun saveOrUpdate(attributes: OAuthAttributes): UserEntity {
        val user = userService.findUserByEmail(attributes.email)?.update(attributes.name, attributes.picture) ?: attributes.toEntity()
        return userService.updateUser(user)
    }

}
```

Error Stack Trace

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes(RequestContextHolder.java:131) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.currentRequestAttributes(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:313) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils$SessionObjectFactory.getObject(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:370) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils$SessionObjectFactory.getObject(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:365) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AutowireUtils$ObjectFactoryDelegatingInvocationHandler.invoke(AutowireUtils.java:289) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at jdk.proxy2.$Proxy148.setAttribute(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at app.myoun.zzalhub.application.service.OAuth2UserService.loadUser(OAuth2UserService.kt:36) ~[main/:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:699) ~[spring-aop-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at app.myoun.zzalhub.application.service.OAuth2UserService$$SpringCGLIB$$0.loadUser(<generated>) ~[main/:?]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.authentication.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(OAuth2LoginAuthenticationProvider.java:117) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:182) ~[spring-security-core-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.java:195) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:231) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:221) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.java:181) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:351) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:400) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:859) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1734) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:10.1.4]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[?:?]
```

According to the error message, the service that handles the request does not contain the request information, or it appears to be handled by another thread. However, this is not accurate and I don't know the solution.

Originally, I expected my code to be stored normally in HttpSession. I tried to find an answer to the same error, but most of the time it was a different problem from mine.

Comment: the service that handles the request does not contain the request information According to the error message,

Answer (score 0):

`OAuth2UserService` is defined as singleton scope, not request scope. As such, the `HttpServletRequest`, `HttpServletResponse`, and `HttpSession` are not available for autowiring.

Instead of trying to interact with the `HttpSession` at the service layer, I'd recommend implementing the `OAuth2User` interface and extend your `User` object, similar to:

```kotlin
class MyOAuth2User : User, OAuth2User {
}
```

Then, when you return that:

```kotlin
override fun loadUser(userRequest: OAuth2UserRequest): OAuth2User {
    // ...

    return MyOAuth2User(user);
}
```

Spring Security will save it to the session as part of the `Authentication` instance it creates later on in the request.

As a side note, I'm not sure why you are recreating the `DefaultOAuth2UserService` on each `loadUser` invocation. I think you can have that as a member variable instead.